# How to for loop and replace an array of values inside a key?

Tags: python, json, ansible-facts

I have a json file (an ansible fact file)

What I'm trying to do is based on an array of keys, if the key is in the file, replace the value... This is so we can replace values people don't want to be made public (IP Address for example).

So far, the python I have can do it if its a simple Key value.... but not if its nested...

So this would be OK and it will replace...

```
"ansible_diff_mode": false,
"ansible_distribution": "CentOS",
"ansible_distribution_file_parsed": true,
"ansible_distribution_file_path": "/etc/redhat-release",
"ansible_distribution_file_variety": "RedHat",
"ansible_distribution_major_version": "7",
"ansible_distribution_release": "Core",
```

However, It can't find these values...

```
"ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
      "1.2.3.4"
  ],
 "ansible_apparmor": {
      "status": "disabled"
  },
```

Here is the code I'm using, and appreciate any pointers...

```
import json

keys_to_sanitise = ['ansible_all_ipv4_addressess','ansible_machine','ansible_bios_version',
                    'ansible_domain','environment']
factfile = 'host.yaml'

def sanitiseDict(d):
    for k in keys_to_sanitise:
        if k in d.keys():
            d.update({k: 'EXCLUDED'})
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            sanitiseDict(v)
    return

with open(factfile, "r") as infile:
    jdata = json.load(infile)
    mydict = {}
    sanitiseDict(jdata)
    print(json.dumps(jdata))
```

Comment: Can you share the factfile so that we can test it out ourselves...

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters you have an extra s in `'ansible_all_ipv4_addressess'`.

You can also clean up the syntax of `sanitiseDict` a bit, to get this, which reads a litte better:

```py
def sanitiseDict(d):
    for k in keys_to_sanitise:
        if k in d:
            d[k] = 'EXCLUDED'
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            sanitiseDict(v)
```